# How to write test for a function which calls another function using jest and enzyme?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using jest and enzyme for testing my app. I've a function as :

```
const someFunc = (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
    arg2.someOtherFunc(arg3);
}
```

Now, I want to write test for function `someFunc`, I've mocked `someOtherFunc` and I'll test whether it'll be called with some arg3 but I'm unable to get how I should write the assertion?

My test should assert that after `someFunc`, it should call `someOtherFunc` with some arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`toHaveBeenCalledWith()`](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-)

```
expect(someOtherFunc).toHaveBeenCalledWith('your args');
```

Comment: But that should be done inside the invocation of `someFunc` write? How do I invoke it?

Comment: ohh okk, I'd just invoke it `someFunc()` and then do `expect(someOtherFunc).toHaveBeenCalledWith('your args');`

Comment: Yes that's it ;) Glad if it helped you

Answer (score 2):

In your case you want to pass the function as a callback
And in your tests you have to Mock it and check if it's being called / being called n times or being called with a specific argument.

Check this example below:

```
// your function
const someFunc = (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
  arg2.someOtherFunc(arg3);
}

// your test file
it("works", () => {
  const arg1 = 'im just any value doesnt matter';
  const arg2 = {
      someOtherFunc: jest.fn(),
    };
  const arg3 = 'argument';

  someFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3);

  // some assertions you can use
  expect(arg2.someOtherFunc).toBeCalled();
  expect(arg2.someOtherFunc).toBeCalledWith('argument');
  expect(arg2.someOtherFunc).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```